# AMP Mobile site cannot able to find the element in DOM for creating selenium script?

Tags: selenium, dom, amp-html

AMP Mobile site cannot able to find the element in DOM for creating selenium script. Is it possible

Comment: what?

Code or just anything please... [ask]

Comment: Can't able to find Mobile response element